# python script to search directories for specific file type

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

Hi guys in the script below I tried to first, list every file and directory in my home directory then check if there is any file with specific extension e.g(.py, .mkv).

It works well with files located in home directory but when I want it to check other directories to see if there is any file there or not, it cant work.

Here it is my code:

```
import os

class Sorter(object):
    path = os.environ['HOME']
    all_dirs = list()
    all_items = list()
    address = None
    movies = list()


    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def list_directories(self):
        dirs = os.listdir(self.path)
        for d in dirs:
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(self.path,d)):
                self.all_dirs.append(d)

            elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.path,d)):
                self.all_items.append(d)

    def find_movies(self):

        for item in self.all_items:
            if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(self.path,item))[1] in ['.mp3','.mkv']:
                self.movies.append(item)
        for directory in self.all_dirs:
            try:
                os.chdir(os.path.join(self.path,directory))
                for i in directory:
                    if os.path.splitext(os.path.join(self.path,item))[1] in ['.mp3','.mkv']:
                        self.movies.append(item)
                os.chdir(self.path)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it cant work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Why do you use a class here? And why are `path`, `all_dirs` etc. defined as class attributes instead of instance attributes (in the `__init__` method)?

Comment: @HåkenLid I used class cause I wanted to make this script a command-line app. I don't understand what you mean instance attributes, path and all_dirs are class attributes. so what is the problem with the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the standard library `pathlib` module and `glob` to search for files by file extension.

The glob dialect is less powerful than in bash, but you can use `**` for recursive subdirectory matching. You can't use bash-style brace expansion `*.{mp3,mkv}`. Instead you can chain the results from multiple glob searches.

```
from pathlib import Path

def find_files(root, extensions):
    for ext in extensions:
        yield from Path(root).glob(f'**/*.{ext}')

for movie in find_files(Path.home() / 'Videos', ['mp4', 'mkv', 'avi']):
    print(movie)
```

Note that Path objects overload the `/` operator so `Path.home() / 'Videos'` will produce a path object representing `/home/username/Videos/`

Answer (score 2):

This seems overly complicated. See this aproach with [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) and list-comprehensions to filter the files:

```
import os
```

### Create files:

```
dirs = [r"./subdir",r"./subdir/tata",r"subdir/tarumpa",r"./dir2b"]
files = ["k.mp4","some.txt","cool.mp3"]

def touch(p,fn):
    with open(os.path.join(p,fn),"w") as f:
        f.write(" ")

for d in dirs:
    os.mkdir(d)
    for f in files:
        touch(d,f)
```

### Find files:

```
movie = []        
music = []        

# os.walk recurses into subdirectories, it returns a generator for each directory
# including the directory its in as root, all subdirs in dirs and all files in 
# files: then it steps into each of the dirs and does the same ...
for root,dirs,files in os.walk("./"):
    # root is the dir we are currently in, f the filename that ends on ...
    movie.extend( (os.path.join(root,f) for f in files if f.endswith(".mp4")) )
    music.extend( (os.path.join(root,f) for f in files if f.endswith(".mp3")) )

print(movie)
print(music)
```

### Output:

```
# movies
['./subdir/k.mp4', './subdir/tarumpa/k.mp4', './subdir/tata/k.mp4', './dir2b/k.mp4']

# music
['./subdir/cool.mp3', './subdir/tarumpa/cool.mp3', 
 './subdir/tata/cool.mp3', './dir2b/cool.mp3']
```